# Puppet: command not found in Debian 8

Tags: debian, puppet, aws

I have just installed puppet master package in Debian 8 using `apt-get` but my puppet command is not working.

```
root@admin:/etc/puppet# puppet
-bash: puppet: command not found
root@admin:/etc/puppet# pwd
/etc/puppet
root@admin:/etc/puppet#
```

I have puppet folder in etc directory with following files and folders

```
root@admin:/etc/puppet# ls

auth.conf  
fileserver.conf  
manifests  
modules 
puppet.conf
```

Is there any way to fix ? I am also searching but when ever I tried to install puppet master using package I experienced this issue, no matter we try amazon linux, centos or RHEL, this issue always occur.

Comment: No, I have tried but there is no folder like that puppetlabs in opt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing the `puppet-common` package. See if the file `/usr/bin/puppet` exists. If not then try installing `puppet-common` using `apt-get install puppet-common`.

Why this package is missing I don't know, it is a dependency from the master `puppet` package so it should have installed at the same time.

Comment: Ojs... exactly this is what I was missing every time....Thank you very much

Comment: @ojs possible that he installed puppet 4 master (via puppet collections repo) and now has installed the puppet 3 agent via debian's repos.

Comment: No jordanm you are telling your experience. Its not like that